# I <have stored> <will have stored> <will store> my thick sweaters and jackets until next winter

Tags: present-perfect, future-time, time-reference

[cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stored):
**(1)** *I **have stored** my thick sweaters and jackets (away) **until next winter***.

"I have stored something" means "I have stored it until now".
Next winter is not now, next winter is a moment in the future.
Therefore, we can't use "until next winter" with "I have stored something".
So (1) is not correct and the correct sentences are:
**(2)** *I **have stored** my thick sweaters and jackets (away) **until now***.
and
**(3)** *I **will store** my thick sweaters and jackets (away) **until next winter***.
**(4)** *I **will have stored** my thick sweaters and jackets (away) **until next winter***.

Am I right? If not, then:
Why is my reasoning not correct?
Why is (1) correct?
What does the present perfect in (1) mean?
Why is it correct to use the present perfect in (1)?
What is the difference between (1), (3) and (4)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're both right and wrong.

There are two slightly different meanings of "store". You're thinking of one, and Cambridge is using the other.

The meaning you're thinking of is something like, "*to *keep* something in an out-of-the-way location temporarily*". With this meaning, it would be incorrect to use present perfect because the action isn't finished yet.

The meaning Cambridge is using is something like, "*to *put* something in an out-of-the-way location*". This second meaning makes sense if at the time of putting them away, the intent was to leave them there until the following winter.

So, while the winter hasn't come yet, the action of *putting* their warm clothing into storage with the intention of leaving them there until winter comes is complete. The *present result* is that those clothes are now in storage, so present perfect applies.